# Azure Function - Increase Environment.ProcessorCount

Tags: c#, azure-functions, parallel.foreach

I have an Azure Function in which I am doing a POST call to an api endpoint and I am doing this using:

```
Parallel.ForEach(activations, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, act =>
    {
        //api call here
    });
```

For a while, I was running this locally and I decided to check the value of `Environment.ProcessorCount` in a deployed Function and the value returned was 2.

The plans are to use functions on a Consumption plan.

Is it possible to increase the value of this variable? I tried to add the application key
`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` with a value of 4, but the result still returned 2 (to be honest, I don't know if this setting is the same thing as the Env.ProcessCount).

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4` directly?

Comment: because I want to get the max available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use .Net 6 or up you can use the `DOTNET_PROCESSOR_COUNT` environment variable to override the number of processors thought to be available by the .NET runtime and reported by the Environment.ProcessorCount property.

For example, if you set `DOTNET_PROCESSOR_COUNT` to 4, `Environment.ProcessorCount` will disregard any process affinity and CPU utilization limit and return 4.

([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6/#optimizing-scaling))

However, if you do that only to set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, why not just do

```
Parallel.ForEach(activations, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = X }, 
    act =>
    {
        //api call here
    });
```

Comment: Tks, Peter! I tested and it worked :-)